# Iterate test steps in soapuI using groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I'm currently trying to generate a report for my test suite in SoapUI.

My old working code was a line this, in the testSuite teardown script:

```
def testc = project.testSuites['TestSuite'].testCases['TestCase'].testSteps['xxxxx']
```

But it had to be duplicated for each new test step.

The code that I'm trying to use is this one:

```
for (service in project.testSuites) {
    for (testCase in service.testCases) {
        for (testStep in testCase.testSteps) {
            someFile.withWriterAppend{out ->out.println testStep.toString()}
        }
    }
}
```

Which is giving me this error:

> groovy?lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: testCases for class: javaUtil.hashMap$Node

Since I'm using the same path to access every test step, I was surprised to not be able to do it with an iteration.

Comment: Benjamin, would you please take a look at below solution to see if that resolves the above mentioned issue? If that helps, you may mark it as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

`project.testSuites` gives you the map. Hence the error. Instead use `project.testSuiteList` which gives the list. So, that the above mentioned error goes away.

Similarly, other objects as well. See below changed code snippet.

```
for (suite in project.testSuiteList) {
    for (kase in suite.testCaseList) {
        for (step in kase.testStepList) {
            someFile.withWriterAppend{out ->out.println testStep.toString()}
        }
    }
}
```